# Mostrar contador de usuarios registrados en mi página web

Tags: php, html, mysql

Mi primer posteo ante una idea que estoy realizando pero me encontré con un problema que no tengo idea de cómo resolverlo.

Estoy realizando un web en PHP con base de datos MySQL y quisiera agregar un contador de usuarios registrados. Es decir, la idea es que haya un script dentro de mi web, que consulte a la base de datos la tabla `usuarios` y me devuelva en un párrafo `<p></p>` el total.

Al iniciar la web incluyo mis archivos PHP, en donde se alojan los datos de servidor.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es_ES">
<?php 
include 'constants/settings.php';
?>
```

Comment: Para poder ayudarte necesito mas informacion, como estas conectando tu base de datos para saber el tipo de comando a usar para la consulta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumiendo que ya realizas una conexión a la base de datos, del tipo `$conn = mysqli_connect(...);`, puedes utilizar esta conexión para obtener la cantidad de usuarios y mostrarla en tu página.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo que puedes utilizar:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(1) AS Total FROM usuarios");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo '<p>Total de usuarios registrados '.$row['Total'].'</p>';
?>
```

Ubica este código en la parte que quieres que aparezca la etiqueta `p` y el total de usuarios.

Como recomendación, lo mejor es que todos los archivos que necesites importar con configuraciones, se encuentre al principio de tu archivo `.php` que contiene las etiquetas HTML, antes de la etiqueta `<html>` o `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

```
<?php 
include 'constants/settings.php';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es_ES">
    <!-- El resto de tu página web -->
</html>
```

Comment: Roxguel, Genio total!!! super agradecido por la ayuda,

Comment: Un placer contribuir con la comunidad. Si la respuesta te fue de utilidad, te invito a marcarla como aceptada, para darle fin al caso.